# Unable to close 'Applications' after update to 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I have updated to 19.04 from 18.10 (which was updated to from 18.04 and maybe even 17.10 before that-don't remember exactly). Now the problem is that when I open Applications (either by Clicking it on dash or opening it using <kbd>Super</kbd> key) and then close it, the Applications overlay stays on and I am not able to open/switch to any other application. I have tried to switch to Wayland, but the only difference was, I was not able to fix this by restarting using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: I just press Super again, or ESC. Doesn't that work for you ? I am using Gnome on Xorg.

Comment: @SorenA I have tries Super, ESC, Alt+F4, clicking other application on Dash... The only thing that works for me is Alt+2 and then 'r'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by disabling the "Workspace Grid" in gnome-shell. First I launched a terminal with Alt+Ctrl+t and then I issued the following command to open the gnome-shell extension preferences:

```
$ gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

In the preferences I disabled the "Workspace Grid":
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMlnR.png)

Lastly, I logged out and in again and the problem was gone.

Comment: It worked. i had to disable also Workspace Matrix extension to make it work, but after re-enabling it (Workspace Matrix, not the Workspace Grid) everything still worked fine (incl. the matrix extension).

Comment: Also for me, the "Workspace Grid" caused the issue, but after installing "Workspace Matrix", everything worked well.